# how to not overwrite the data already in the text file when i want to add more data

Tags: java, formatter

this is the code i use when opening the txt file but it overwrites the data everytime i want to put in more data.

```
private  Formatter X;
    private File Y = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Property Charge Management System\\users.txt");
    private Scanner Z;
    public  String[][] PCMSarray;
    public boolean OpenFile() {
        try{
            if(Y.exists()==false){
                X = new Formatter("users.txt");
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File has not yet been created.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the code i use to write to the file but this works.

```
public void WriteToFilecmd(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your First name");
        String Fname = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Last name");
        String Lname = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Password");
        String Password = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your user ID");
        String ID = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the first address line of your Property");
        String addressln1 = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second address line of your Property");
        String addressln2 = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the third address line of your Property");
        String addressln3 = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the properties estimated market value");
        String EstimatedPropertyValue = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your tax owed");
        String Taxowed = input.next();
        input.close();

        X.format("%1$20s %2$20s %3$20s %4$20s %5$20s %6$20s %7$20s %8$20s %9$20s \n",Fname,Lname,Password,ID,addressln1,addressln2,addressln3,EstimatedPropertyValue,Taxowed);
    }
```

Comment: Might want to tag it with the language it's written in, seemingly java

Comment: Some miscellaneous tips: Start variable names with lower case letters ("id", not "ID") because following Java naming convention goes a long way toward readability. Use relevant variable names (call a Scanner "scanner", not "Z"). Try to post an entire compilable example, and trim it down so we can focus on the important parts (the details of your WriteToFilecmd method are not relevant to your question). Call input.close() in a finally block to make sure it always gets executed even if an exception is thrown. Write "!y.exists()", not "y.exists()==false". Prefer List<List<String>> to String[][].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different constructor for the Formatter, one that takes a FileWriter (which is Appendable), and construct the FileWriter so that it appends to the end of the file:

```
// the second boolean parameter, true, marks the file for appending
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true); 
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(fileWriter);
```

As an aside, please learn and follow Java naming rules, else your code will not be easily understood by others (namely **us**!). Variable and method names should begin with lower-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess in a number of respects, but I think that the problem is that you are testing:

```
  C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Property Charge Management System\\users.txt
```

but then you are opening

```
  users.txt
```

... which happens to be a different file because your "current directory" is not what you think it should be.

Even if that is not what is causing your problem, you should fix it.  The way the code is currently written it will break if your current directory is not "C:\Users\user\workspace\Property Charge Management System" when the code is executed.

---

If you really want to *append* to the file instead of overwriting it, then you need to use a `Formatter` constructor that takes an opened output stream or writer ... and supply it with a stream that has been opened in append mode.

---

I should also not that you've made a serious style mistake in your code.  The universal rule for Java code is that variable names and method names **must** start with a lower-case letter.  People assume that anything that starts with an upper-case letter is a class ... unless the name is ALL_CAPITALS, which is reserved for manifest constants.